# Isolated circuits: can their reference voltages (GNDs) be at the same potential?

Tags: isolation, physics, theory, circuit-theory

Suppose there are two independent circuits isolated from each other. If they are isolated, the impedance is very high between them (ideally infinite) and there is no current flowing from one to the other.

But if there is no current between them, because impedance is so high, shouldn't they be at the same voltage?

My first answer would be, if the circuits are isolated, one floating from the other, voltage is not predictable between both circuits.

Let's say we use a 100 gigaohm resistor to connect both grounds, so there is still plenty isolation but now they are galvanically related. There's a big impedance between both circuits and current is not flowing from one to the other, so now they must be almost at the same voltage... Right?

Connected through a big resistor or coupled through air, if there is a big impedance between circuits, shouldn't they be at the same voltage? Isn't it somehow contradictory?

Comment: On the contrary, if there is a very high resistance, there can be a large voltage difference with an unmeasurably small current.

Comment: what if your isolation is a 1:1 transformer, with 100pF primary-secondary capacitance, with 10 volt in 10 nanosecond pulses coupling thru the transformer. The current will be I = C * dV/dT = 1e-10Farad * 1volt/nanoSec slew rate, and I = 0.1 amp, needing a return path. That charge will explore and utilize all possible return paths.

Answer (score 2):

There are few paradoxes in engineering because the real world doesn't have a lot of zeros or infinities, and the ones we create are handled by calculus.

It's not that current doesn't flow between isolated circuits.  If they were truly isolated, you'd be in Heisenberg territory, but in normal situations the resistance between them is very large.  Due to the high resistance, a voltage difference between them causes only a small, possibly immeasurable current to flow between them...but in order to measure this, you'd have to establish a connection between the two circuits anyway.

Whenever you find logical inconsistencies based on zeroes and infinities, they can usually be resolved by substituting "very small" and "very large."